# Why can't combine the two configuration file --/home/normal/.bashrc and /root/.bashrc-- into just one file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, history

Os : debian8.
There are two users :normal and root.

```
touch /var/log/all.log
chmod  777  /var/log/all.log
```

For normal.

```
vim  /home/normal/.bashrc
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y-%m-%d:%H-%M-%S:  `whoami` : "    
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history  > /var/log/all.log'

source /home/normal/.bashrc
```

All the history command for normal(the user) will write into /var/log/all.log.

For root the same way.

```
vim  /root/.bashrc
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y-%m-%d:%H-%M-%S:  `whoami` : "    
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history  > /var/log/all.log'

source /root/.bashrc
```

All the history command for root(the user) will write into /var/log/all.log.

Now i want to combine the two configuration file into one file.
Delete the two lines in both /home/normal/.bashrc and /root/.bashrc .
1. Combine them into `/etc/profile`.

```
vim  /etc/profile    
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y-%m-%d:%H-%M-%S:  `whoami` : "    
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history  > /var/log/all.log'    

source /etc/profile
```

All the history info for normal can't be written into /var/log/all.log.
All the history info for root can be written into /var/log/all.log.
2. Combine them into /etc/bash.bashrc .

```
vim  /etc/bash.bashrc     
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y-%m-%d:%H-%M-%S:  `whoami` : "    
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history  > /var/log/all.log'

source /etc/bash.bashrc
```

All the history info for normal can't be written into /var/log/all.log.
All the history info for root can be written into /var/log/all.log.

Why can't combine the two configuration file --/home/normal/.bashrc and /root/.bashrc-- into just one file?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is $HISTFILE, and you get that information from `man bash`:

`HISTFILE ---- The name of the file in which command history is saved (see HISTORY below).  The default value is ~/.bash_history.  If unset, the command history is not saved when a shell exits.`

So, set $HISTFILE to /var/log/all.log in your profile and that should do it.

`export HISTFILE=/var/log/all.log`

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so, please mark it as the correct answer.